# Dart strong mode: error on anonymous function return

Tags: dart

I get the following error.
`The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type '() -> dynamic'`
The example is:

```
outerFunc(somevar) {
    return () {....} 
}
anOtherFunction(func()) {....}

anOtherFunction(outerFunc('test'));
```

These occurs when I return an anonymous function, in strong mode with the analysis_options.yaml on.

```
strong-mode:
  implicit-casts: false
```

Comment: Adding your own type resolves this issue `typedef Function funcType();` then using it like `anOtherFunction(outerFunc('test') as funcType);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outerFunc` doesn't specify a return type, therefore `dynamic` is assumed.
You can create a typedef and use it as return type for `outerFunc`.
The function type can't be inferred from the return statement.

```dart
typedef dynamic F();

F outerFunc(somevar) {
  return () {};
}
```

You can also write the function type in-line

```dart
dynamic Function() outerFunc(somevar) {
  return () {};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I went this route